# How to print the minimum of the value from the data?

Tags: c

/*Test Average Problem Revision #1: Write a program that reads in the same 
file as above, but also calculates the minimum and maximum test scores, as 
well as which test number both of those were. (For example, if the test scores 
in the file were 70, 85, 99, 67 and 83, then the minimum test score was 67 on test #4 and the maximum test score was 99 on test #3.) Have your program print out this 
information to the screen. */

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   

    int num, start;

    int num_test, score, max=0, min=0, maxi, mini;

    FILE*ifp, *ofp;

    ifp = fopen("test.in.txt", "r");

    ofp = fopen("test.max.txt", "w");

    fscanf(ifp,"%d", &num);

    for ( start = 1; start <= num; start++)
    {
        fscanf(ifp,"%d %d", &num_test, &score);

        fprintf(ofp,"Test: %d    score: %d  \n", num_test, score);


        if (score > max)

        {
            max = score;  

            maxi = num_test;

        }


        if (score < min)

        {
            min = score;

            mini = num_test;
        }

    }
        fprintf(ofp,"\n\nMax = Test:%d Score: %d\n",maxi, max);

        fprintf(ofp,"\nMin = Test:%d Score: %d\n",mini, min);

    fclose(ifp);

    fclose(ofp);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Test: 1    score: 60  
Test: 2    score: 99  
Test: 3    score: 65  
Test: 4    score: 57  
Test: 5    score: 85  
Test: 6    score: 78  
Test: 7    score: 87  
Test: 8    score: 90  


Max = Test:2 Score: 99

Min = Test:0 Score: 0

Comment: That is the data above. It prints everything correctly, except the minimum.

Comment: You might want to read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking a good question is the most important part of ensuring good answers. Specifically, include an actual question, supported by showing the output you expected, and the output you got instead. Keep in mind you can edit your own question to add the missing details.

Comment: initialise min to 2^32-1 = 2147483647. this is the max value of a 32 bit int

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem of initialization. You need to initialize `max` with the lowest value possible according to the algorithm (by sheer chance you did it) and `min` with the highest value possible (you failed to do it).

A safe bet for initializing `min` id the highest value possible for that respective data type.

For `int`, that value could be 2^32-1 (if `int` is represented on 32 bits).

If you do not want to handle huge numbers, you should then analyze your problem, to understand the maximum value possible. This is more dangerous, because the number of the problem may change, and then the algorithm may fail.

---

An alternative would be to find the values in 2 steps - it will probably take longer, but still be safe.

Step 1: find the maximum.

Step 2: initialize `min` = `max` and then find the minimum.

Comment: The question is tagged “C”, so the OP's compiler **must** define `INT_MAX` when `limits.h` is included. There are no “if it is defined by …” about it.

Comment: From my experience, many things "must" but actually "don't". Additionally, we do not know how old the compiler is, and how much conforming. I learned this lesson the hard way - to not make assumptions.

Comment: In other words, your answer would help the OP more by stating that `limits.h` must be included and then `INT_MAX` will be defined if what they have is actually a C compiler, than just implying that it may be not be defined. (My own experience, for what it's worth, is that I have encountered more C programmers who blame the compiler for their own mistakes than compilers that do not at least implement C89. I'm not saying you are in this case, I'm just saying that you have to respect the rules and include the correct header before you can blame the compiler for not defining the macro.)

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm obliges initializing `min, max` with the extreme opposite `int` values, not 0 - which is in the middle of the `int` range.

Useful limits in `limits.h`. [@Pascal Cuoq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56697805/how-to-print-the-minimum-of-the-value-from-the-data/56703763#comment99960990_56697914)

```
// max=0, min=0
max=INT_MIN, min=INT_MAX
```

---

Note: Code properly does a `if` and not `else if` as the later would fail when all test values are the same.

```
if (score < min)
// else if (score < min)
```

---

Robust code would check the return value of `fscanf()` to insure successful reading occurred. (2 places)

```
// fscanf(ifp,"%d %d", &num_test, &score);
if (fscanf(ifp,"%d %d", &num_test, &score) != 2) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected input\n");
  return EXIT_FAILURE; 
}
```

Also check `fopen()` success (2 places)

```
ifp = fopen("test.in.txt", "r");
if (ifp == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open read file\n");
  return EXIT_FAILURE; 
}
```